# Sort combobox alphabetically WPF

Tags: wpf, sorting

I have a lot off combo boxes in my project. I need to sort there items alphabetically.
I can't sort them individually in SQL query not through LINQ where data in loading .
I want to put a hook in Combox ,whenever any combox get data in project it sort in automatically.
How I can do that ? What and where changes should I made to generically sort all combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CollectionViewSource`

On XAML side:
Here you need to set **cm** as namespace

```
xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System"
```

...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=YourItemSource}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
       <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

... Usage ..

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewSource}}" />
```